# Database query - how to put the result in the HTML Code?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a database where the path of pictures are stored. Now I want to get the path of the picture and the description but I dont know how to surround the data with HTML-Code. A "(Html-Code) " indicates Html-Code but in my example it is a bit more complicated. Maybe it is wrong the way I want to do it but I dont know another way.

Here the Php-Code

```
   <?php include ("data_con.php"); 

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

 if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 

$sql = "SELECT Dateipfad FROM last_upload WHERE ID = 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);    

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); {


}
}    else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
  echo "Connected successfully";?>
```

Here the Html-Code

```
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 no-gutter">
<div class="rahmen"> <img src="Pic/OP.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image"> 
<p>Episode 1</p></div>
```

First of all I just want to have the path of the file (Dateipfad) ecchoed in

```
<img src="Pic/Op.jp">
```

therefore I need to make it like that

```
<img="echo .row[Dateipfad]."
```

But all the " to indicate the html code is really hard.

The code have to be in

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); {


}
```

but with all the HTML-Code it is really hard and doesnt work for me. I think i do it completly wrong. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like you need to go read up on some syntax basics. http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: share your database table last_upload screenshot.

Comment: There are not only ID and Dateipfad but the most important know are the two. Here is the Link. I used the paths just to try https://www.pic-upload.de/view-33639941/s.png.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Method 1**

```
<?php $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Dateipfad FROM last_upload WHERE ID = 1";

if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    echo '<img src ="$row['value']">'$row['value']'</img>';
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
echo "Connected successfully";
```

### **Method Two**

```
<?php $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT Dateipfad FROM last_upload WHERE ID = 1";

if ( $result = $conn->query($sql) ) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ ?>
    // write html here
    <ul>
      <li>Just a test</li>
      <li>Another test</li>
    </ul>
    <img src ="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>"><?php echo $row['value']; ?></img>
  <?php }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
echo "Connected successfully";
```

Comment: But what is with the other code which surrounded the img tag?

Comment: Check my update. Both way are possible and not need to work about performance. The method 2 can be used if you want to display a large block of code. Tag My answer as solved if this fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are looking for is something akin to

`<img src="<?= $row[Dateipfad] ?>" />`

Also, are you sure that you don't want to iterate on all the results? Will your query always return a single result or none at all?

Comment: I try it later with all results but the code I want to surround it is different

Answer (score 0):

update

```
if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){?>
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5 no-gutter">
        <div class="rahmen"> <img src="<?php echo $row['Dateipfad']; ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
          <p>Episode 1</p>
       </div>
      </div>
    <?php}
}
```

Comment: But what is with the other code which surrounds the img tag

Comment: $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); {


} the code must be in it or not? Do you have the time to change my code and post the whole code here, So I would see where I am wrong..

Comment: yes it should be in the block, and you need different code

Comment: This makes no sense for me right now... Could you show me the right way or would it be too much?

Comment: But what is with all the divs and that. I mean I use bootstrap and the img have to be between those divs but I couldnt do that. Thats what I meant

Comment: see again above

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo row[Dateipfad]; ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

And don't use short handed echo statement `<?= ?>` for my sake.

Comment: This is what I dont understand. The code have to be in                       
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); {


    } or not?